# Which anime's female character was the most famous across the internet in 2015?

Tags: resources

Which anime's female character was the most famous across the internet from **JAN-2015** to **MARCH-2016** (Winter 2015 to Spring 2016)?

For clarification purpose:

My question is focused on data such as polls, internet page hits, imageboard posts or any other method that proves to be accurate. *(Meaning: This is not a opinion based question. If you want to leave a opinion do so in the comments.)*

As an example, when the TV Show "*Amagi Brilliant Park*" aired, the main character Isuzu Sento was all over the internet, with several doujinshis, fan-made images, and uses of this character in anime sites.

Further exemplifying: Suzumiya Haruhi (SHnY), Hatsune Miku (idol), Asuna (SAO), Mikasa (SnK) are used a lot over the internet and all are easily recognized faces, and this is what I'm looking for, but from the latest year only.

What I want this for: I'm making an app which will use the female character.

Comment: Kaguya(Naruto) = RKO outta of no where Anime version

Comment: I think Famitsu does character polls by gender. I wouldn't know how to find it since I can't read Japanese. You might also want to frame your question this way: ask for polls from magazines specifically to narrow and focus your question. The two that I know of are Famitsu and Dengeki.

Comment: Hi OP!  I find your question quite interesting, still I see a few issues which are the following one : - You should define what you call "lastest year" (full 2015 year or 24 March 2015 to 24 March 2016). - Your question may be too broad (IMO) and you maybe should define a smaller scope (ex : most famous female character in last year shonens).

Comment: this is not question . . .

Comment: What do you mean, @NamikazeSheena?

Comment: Good method to ask here if you want to make an application. However, I think you should define the boundaries by saying "latest". Like, in 2016-Winter, 2016-Spring, or 2014-2016? And this quite based on opinion. I think, you had better ask a forum or something like MyAnimeList, or you should follow the current market. Or maybe, use chat room of SE Anime?

Comment: The problems I saw with this question: a) As Ikaros said, you don't define "the latest year", b) you don't define "most famous" or "draw some attention", c) a consequence of (b), you don't define what kinds of "facts/statistics" would answer this question for you. If you just want a popularity poll, there are lots online; otherwise this question reads a lot like "Who's the best recent female character?" which is broad and opinion-based; whether you ask for facts or not, there are none to be given.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments you left, I've rephrased my entire post and I believe now its better and less broad.

Comment: Thanks for improving your question! I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few different ways of interpreting your question. Interpretation #1 is "among all characters who appeared in anime from Jan 2015 to Mar 2016, which of them is most popular on the internet by metrics X, Y, and Z". Interpretation #2 is "among all characters who appeared in anime from Jan 2015 to Mar 2016, which of them is most popular on the internet *as a consequence of their appearing in the anime* by metrics X, Y, and Z". Interpretation #2 is considerably more difficult to measure, but it may be more relevant to you.

It also matters whether by "the internet" you mean "all of the internet" or "the English-speaking internet", because Japanese viewers tend to have systematically different tastes than non-Japanese viewers.

### #1 / all

Under interpretation #1 and "all of the internet", the answer almost surely has to be someone from *Kantai Collection*, which is the biggest thing since sliced Touhou. Take your pick from Shimakaze (an early character who achieved high popularity and has maintained it since); Fubuki (brought to prominence by the anime); Kashima (the newest high-popularity character from the franchise); or any number of other shipgirls. (I think Shimakaze wins by most metrics, including pixiv illustrations - [24000 as of now](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E5%B3%B6%E9%A2%A8); [this pixiv poll from 2014](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nejC.jpg) by a large margin; etc. But she did have a considerable head start, being ship #10.)

### #1 / English

Under interpretation #1 and "the English-speaking internet", sites like MAL are good places to look.

- On MAL, the [top-ranking female characters](http://myanimelist.net/character.php) from anime that aired during the time period in question are Senjougahara Hitagi (*Monogatari*), Suzumiya Haruhi (via *Nagato Yuki-chan*), Saber (*Fate*), and Erza Scarlet (*Fairy Tail*).
- On [Anime-Planet](http://www.anime-planet.com/characters/top-loved) (which I think skews to a more casual demographic than MAL), the list is Erza Scarlet, Hyuuga Hinata (*Naruto*), Suzumiya Haruhi, and Lucy Heartfilia (*Fairy Tail*).
- [AniDB](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=characterlist&orderby.rating=0.2&orderby.name=1.1&orderbar=0&noalias=1) is a bit more difficult to work with since they have ratings rather than just "likes", but the toppers by raw rating (without adjusting for confidence based on number of ratings) are Miyauchi Renge (*Non Non Biyori*, twice!), Kongou (*KanColle*), Cure Beat (*PreCure*), and Cure Moonlight (*PreCure*)

### #2 / all

Under interpretation #2 and "all of the internet", the answer may not be someone from *KanColle*, because the anime, while still very popular, was not quite as ridiculously popular as the game on which it is based.

Idol shows are another common source of super-popular female characters. Within the time period under consideration, *Love Live!* and *Idolmaster* both aired, and both of these shows derive more of their popularity from TV than *KanColle* does. I know that *Love Live!* has (had) periodic character polls, but I can't find many of them at the moment. [Here's one from Jan 2016 ish](http://matome.naver.jp/odai/2142631062822870101) which has Nico at the top (see, Japan has weird taste), and [another one from back in 2013](http://www.lovelive-anime.jp/otonokizaka/sp_election.html) that has Maki at the top (okay, not *that* weird). No idea whether *Idolmaster* does them too.

Other than that, I don't have any good data, but my impression is that the various female leads from *Saekano*, *Fate*, *Oregairu*, and *Monogatari* are also potential contenders under this interpretation.

### #2 / English

For the English-speaking internet, interpretations #1 and #2 are actualyl mostly the same, since most of the English-speaking internet's exposure to "otaku culture" is through anime, with virtually no non-anime media achieving prominence anywhere near the most popular anime. (Contrast Japan, where *KanColle*, the game, is very much a thing.)

Perhaps the key exceptions are a select few visual novels like *Fate/stay night* and *Muv-Luv*; and wildly popular manga like *One Punch Man* and *Shingeki no Kyojin* (though these things pretty much always get anime adaptations eventually). But I'm not aware of any non-anime properties like this during the time period under consideration, so I expect no real difference between interpretations #1 and #2.

## Miscellaneous notes

One other well-known source for this kind of thing is *Newtype* magazine's monthly character polls. But I warn you in advance, their polls skew in very strange ways. For example, Kira Yamato is almost perpetually ranked, despite not having been on TV since 2005. Anyway, I found most of these for the time period in question, and it turns out that Saber tops about half the polls and places in the top 3 in the rest.

## My personal take

If you choose to include *KanColle*, I think the obvious answer is Shimakaze, or possibly Kongou, given that you want a character with high recognizability in the vein of Haruhi/Asuna/Mikasa/etc.

If you choose to exclude *KanColle*, which may also be reasonable depending on your target audience, I would recommend a character from *Monogatari*, which has had 7 years to stew in the minds of people, yet is still putting out new animated content. Senjougahara is probably the most recognizable of them, but Shinobu/Kiss-Shot is more topical, given that *Kizumonogatari* is literally happening this year. The other reasonable option I see is Tatsumaki from *One Punch Man*, too, given the broad popularity of that show with English-speaking audiences.

Alternatively, you could just use Mikasa. *Jiyuu no Tsubasa* (recap movie #2) did premiere in June 2015, after all.

Comment: Nico Nico is my Love Live waifu and I mislike your implication that she is a weird taste. (Acquired, maybe, like Durian fruit.) [Here's](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/the-list/2015-07-25/.90792) a 2015 poll run by Anime News Network (scroll to the bottom of the page) where Maki comes out on top, followed by Nico and then Nozomi.

Comment: Your answer is impeccable, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks for your time answering it :D